# Core Data unexpectedly recreates database on every launch

Tags: ios, core-data, document, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Making a document based core data app.

I have a method that loads projects from core data. Seems to work perfectly as I am creating and loading projects in my app. This means that information is being saved and fetched in the core data document.

**The problem is that every time I open my app a new document is created. This is confusing, as mentioned above I can save and retrieve as much data as I want as long as the app is open.**

The code below worked before for weeks while developing but is now broken somehow. Every time I start the app it logs "CREATE DOCUMENT", and I get a blank doc with no saved data apparently.

```
- (void)openDatabase {
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[myManagedDocument.fileURL path]]) {
        [myManagedDocument saveToURL:myManagedDocument.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL sucess) {
            [self loadCurrentProjectFromCoreData];
             NSLog(@"CREATE DOCUMENT");
        }];
    } else if (myManagedDocument.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
            NSLog(@"DOCUMENT EXISTS, LOAD DOCUMENT");
        [myManagedDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL sucess) {
            [self loadCurrentProjectFromCoreData];
        }];
    } else if (myManagedDocument.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
    [self loadCurrentProjectFromCoreData];
        NSLog(@"DOCUMENT LOADED");
    }
}
```